# Clion & CMake: add_subdirectory, choose build type

Tags: cmake, clion

CLion, 1 Master project (executable), 4 linked libraries (using add_subdirectory).

Builds fine in Debug, but using Release, the main application is build as Release while the sub projects are still compiled and linked in Debug.

Why is not CLion/CMake compiling the subdirectory targets with the same build type?
How can I tell, if I have to, to CLion or CMake (not sure who's responsible for the task)
which kind of build I want for the subdirectories?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The value gets propagated correctly and it simply works if nothing messes with it.
Another statement in the CMakeLists.txt was forcing the working directory of the sub-projects, the build was actually matching release and debug, just outputting in the wrong place and misleading a lot!